# How can I have an undo function in my delete button in CRUD table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

```
const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    //if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete?"))
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        //alert("deleted");
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID !== ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      const my_serial = key + pageNumber * customersPerPage;

      return (
        <tr>
          {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      
          <td>{my_serial + 1}</td>
      */}
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
```

How can I have an undo function in my delete button in CRUD table?
I have a delete function on my button, is it possible to add an undo function when I delete? and possibly a confirmation message.

On the delete button right at the bottom of the code, it calls function onClick.

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you have soft delete feature inside back-end. _Do you_?

Comment: @Justinas What's a soft delete feature on the backend? Currently My backend is mysql and Im deleting it from the database when i press delete.

Comment: Soft delete is when you mark row as deleted in some column, then you just exclude these results from queries. Then you can undelete. Otherwise you must re-send same data again to create it

Comment: @Justinas So how can I undo the delete?

Comment: MySql does not have such concept. You delete it permanently. So either you set `is_deleted` to 0/1 or you create same element again when undeleting

Comment: @Justinas How do I create the same element again when undeleting in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233540/discussion-between-fyceheist-and-justinas).